# NodeJs EventEmitter get listeners check if listener is of type on or once

Tags: javascript, node.js, eventemitter

I am using node v8.9.4 and I want to get listeners of an `EventEmitter` in order to reattach them to another EventEmitter (I use an API that can handle only one `EventEmitter` as parameter but got have to handle one internal emitter and one external emitter).

I need to find out, if current listener for an eventName is attached by `.on` or by `.once`.

Since I am not using the latest node version, I am not able to use `.rawListeners` as described in the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_rawlisteners_eventname).

```
const emitter1 = new EventEmitter();
const emitter2 = new EventEmitter();

emitter1.on('bam', (...args) => {
    // exec...
});

emitter1.once('bazinga', (...args) => {
    // exec...
});

emitter2.once('bam', (...args) => {
    // exec...
});

emitter2.on('bazinga', (...args) => {
    // exec...
});

const eventNames = emitter2.eventNames();
for (let eventName of eventNames) {     
    // in node 9 i would to the following...
    const listeners = emitter2.rawListeners(eventName);
    if (listeners[0].listener) {
        emitter1.once(eventName, listeners[0].listener);
    } else {
        emitter1.on(eventName, listeners[0]); 
    }
    // in node 8 idk...
}
```

Is it possible to get that information by using the 8.x LTS API?

(If not is there an alternative approach of reattaching events from one EventEmitter to another?)

Comment: You should be able to get the events of an emitter with `emitter._events`. It's an object whose keys are event names and values are either a single function or an array of functions depending on multiple listeners are attached to the same event name. If you need to check if a listener are attached to `.once` you can use `Function.name` and match for the string `onceWrapper` with `String.includes` method. E.g `listener.name.includes('onceWrapper')`.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. You can convert it to an answer if you want.